# Change Value of a label when hovering over asp:ImageButton

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my welcome page, there is a series of 6 asp:ImageButton 's. When hovered over, the image will swap to create the effect of it changing from gray to orange through the use of two separate images. I have that part coded and working like a charm.

Now for the secondary part of this adventure, I have two labels present, one for the title, and one for the description. These will be blank until the user hovers over one of the buttons, then the title label should correspond to the title of the page, and the description label should correspond to the description of the page. When the user hovers out of the button, the button will turn back to gray, and the labels become invisible or blank.

This is the code format for one of the buttons I have in its current state:

The button in ASP

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgContact" runat="server" CssClass="tiles" ImageUrl="~/images/inContact.png" />
```

The C# code behind located in the Page_Load event handler

```
imgContact.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.src='images/acContact.png'");
            imgContact.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.src='images/inContact.png'");
```

The labels to be used in this page are lblTitle and lblDescription. I have tried doing this with if statements within the Page_Load event, but I have wound up with no luck there, particularly when trying to work with an elusive event handler that I would assume would be OnMouseOver, but that doesn't appear to be what I am looking for due to the error it creates whenever I try using it or something similar.

I want to avoid JavaScript as much as possible and stick with C# for this. Where should I start? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Curious what your aversion to JavaScript is, considering it is a presentation change, which is perfectly suited for JavaScript / jQuery.

Comment: For now, I am just not as familiar with it as I am C#. I am a hobby developer and self taught with a fair understanding of how C# works. I have the murach books on JavaScript, but with life and work, I haven't had the chance to crack the cover of that or my SQL book. So for now, if I do it in C#, if I ever have an issue with anything it will be easier for me to troubleshoot, but eventually I will start working with JS, and eventually work it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want to achive.

Add this to your aspx page this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="title label" CssClass="TitleLabel"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" CssClass="DecriptionLabel" Text="description label"></asp:TextBox>
```

and change in code behind to this

```
imgContact.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.src='images/acContact.png';document.getElementsByClassName('TitleLabel')[0].value='first title';document.getElementsByClassName('DecriptionLabel')[0].value='first description'");
imgContact.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.src='images/inContact.png';document.getElementsByClassName('TitleLabel')[0].value='title label';document.getElementsByClassName('DecriptionLabel')[0].value='description label'");
```

You say that you don't want to use javascript but using *imgContact.Attributes* function to add *onmouseover* and *onmouseout* you are adding javascript to webpage :) take a look on source off webpage to see how the generated code looks like. My answer will solve your issue but try to understand how it works. Have fun ;)

Comment: I implemented that code and it works partially. After making the modification necessary to use the correct images for each of the 6 buttons and title and description, I have the first button and the last button working flawlessly - but the four in the middle do not do anything when I mouse over them.

Comment: Scratch that... The error was on my part as a typo. Congratulations, the answer is yours. Thank you kindly for the fast reply. On a side note regarding the JS, looking at the output on the client side, I had no idea that was taking place. Thanks for pointing that out, as it proved helpful in troubleshooting my typo.